# how to make background fit on screen bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a background fit screen. without a content inside it. how to make that

**CSS**

```
#test {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="body">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sue lorem ipsum dolor sue </p>
</div>
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dawv6zmk/4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add width to `100%` and height to `100vh` and apply background to it.

Your CSS should look like:

```
#test{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
    background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L93hk3fp/

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this

```
#test{
      background:url('http://placehold.it/350x150') no-repeat center center; //Display image full screen
      min-height:100%;  //ensure that it always take full screen to browser window
      background-size:cover;
     }
```